# MySQL Volleyball Standings

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have a database table full of game by game results and want to know if I can calculate the following:

- GP (games played)
- Wins
- Loses
- Points (2 points for each win, 1 point for each lose)

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `home_team_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `home_score` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visit_team_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visit_score` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tcl_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

And a few testing results:

```
INSERT INTO `results` VALUES(1, 1, 21, 2, 25, 68);
INSERT INTO `results` VALUES(2, 3, 21, 4, 17, 68);
INSERT INTO `results` VALUES(3, 1, 25, 3, 9, 68);
INSERT INTO `results` VALUES(4, 2, 7, 4, 22, 68);
INSERT INTO `results` VALUES(5, 1, 19, 4, 20, 68);
INSERT INTO `results` VALUES(6, 2, 24, 3, 26, 68);
```

Here is what a final table would look something like this (results are not completely accurate):

```
+-------------------+----+------+-------+--------+
| Team Name         | GP | Wins | Loses | Points |
+-------------------+----+------+-------+--------+
| Spikers           |  4 |    4 |     0 |      8 |
| Leapers           |  4 |    2 |     2 |      6 |
| Ground Control    |  4 |    1 |     3 |      5 |
| Touch Guys        |  4 |    0 |     4 |      4 |
+-------------------+----+------+-------+--------+
```

Need to add WHERE clause for

```
tcl_id
```

like so:

WHERE results.tcl_id = 68

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT
    team_id,
    COUNT(*) AS GP,
    SUM(is_win) AS Wins,
    SUM(NOT is_win) AS Losses,
    2 * SUM(is_win) + SUM(NOT is_win) AS Points
FROM
(
    SELECT
        home_team_id AS team_id,
        home_score > visit_score AS is_win
    FROM results
    WHERE tcl_id = 68
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        visit_team_id AS team_id,
        home_score < visit_score AS is_win
    FROM results
    WHERE tcl_id = 68
) T1
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

Output for your example data:

```
4, 3, 2, 1, 5
3, 3, 2, 1, 5
1, 3, 1, 2, 4
2, 3, 1, 2, 4
```

Notes:

- Your example data doesn't seem to match with your expected output - your test data only has 6 games played, but your expected output has 8 games. This is why my output is different from yours.
- You haven't provided the table for getting the team names from the team ids. Just join with your table with the team names to get the result in the format you want.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You make it look so simple, but I'm sure other have had this issue before. One question, I joined the `teams` table no problem but I have to add something to the WHERE clause and its giving me an error. In the `results` table there is another field named `tcl_id` (`results`.`tcl_id`).  I need to add WHERE `tcl_id` = "68" but its giving me this error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'results.tcl_id' in 'where clause'
I'm not sure what the issue is... is it the UNION that is not allowing me to access the `results` table as is?

Comment: @Torez: Replace `FROM results` with `FROM results WHERE tcl_id = '68'` in **both** places and it should work.

Comment: What do you use to format your sql? (sorry for being off-topic).

Comment: @~unutbu: I write MySQL code in MySQL query analyzer and just use the space bar repeatedly to format it. So nothing fancy I'm afraid. :( I may write a tool one day but the time spent formatting is generally quite small compared to other activities so I haven't bothered yet.